# toggle checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this code,

```
function checkboxToggle(source,className) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
  $("input[type='checkbox']."+className).change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox']."+className);
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        source.checked = true;
    }else{
        source.checked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

The source is the checkbox for Select All.
The className is the class name of the checkboxes needed to change.
The for loop is a loop to change the checkboxes state that depends on the "Select All" state.
I also added .change event that will change the "Select All" state when a checkbox state is changed.

This code is working, but my problem is, I would like to make this code smaller.
Is it possible to make this code smaller?

Comment: See [ask] and **[mcve]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is too long:

```
checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
   checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
 }
```

Using jquery, this can be something like:

```
$(classname).prop('checked', source.checked);
```

I don't quite understand why your .change function is inside the checkBoxToggle function. I think that's a mistake.

Comment: I put the .change function inside so I can get the className.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLue3vs/1/).

I created a simple form (in the fiddle there are two)

```
<form>
    <label for="checkbox-all">Select All</label>
    <input id="checkbox-all" class="check-all" type="checkbox" />

    <label for="checkbox-01">01</label>
    <input id="checkbox-01" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />

    <label for="checkbox-02">02</label>
    <input id="checkbox-02" class="" type="checkbox" />

    <label for="checkbox-03">03</label>
    <input id="checkbox-03" class="" type="checkbox" />

    <label for="checkbox-04">04</label>
    <input id="checkbox-04" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />

    <label for="checkbox-05">05</label>
    <input id="checkbox-05" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

And then some jQuery:

```
<script>

function checkAll(element, className) {

    var checkboxesToChange = typeof(className) === 'undefined' || className === ''  ? 'input[type="checkbox"]' : '.'+className;

    var $form = $(element).closest('form');
    var $checkboxes = $form.find(checkboxesToChange);

    if($(element).is(':checked')){
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    }

}

$('.check-all').on('change', function(){
    checkAll(this);
    //checkAll(this, 'checkboxes'); 
})

</script>
```

If you're looking to just have a select all you can toggle, this will do that. It also accepts a second parameter where it will only toggle on and off the checkboxes with the class you specify.

Hope this helps, or at least provides some insight as to how you can reduce the code.